# How does Stack Overflow synchronize vote up/down made by same login across different browsers/computers?

Tags: discussion, live-refresh, technical

I recently noticed a feature of Stack Overflow's website and after thinking for a while didn't fully understand how this feature is implemented. I am a freshman to front end.

**The test is simple:**

Open two browsers (in my test, one Firefox, one Chrome), log in with your Stack Overflow account, on both browsers. Open the same page of any question in Stack Overflow on both browsers. Then, click "vote up" of this question on Chrome. So the votes of this question, seeing from this page, increases by one.

But then the interesting thing happens: The Firefox, on which I logged in and opened the page of the same question, but didn't click anything on it, the votes of this question automatically increase by one as well, no page refreshing. Opening Firebug's -> Net tab, no package flow shown.

Using another computer instead of another browser, result is the same.

**My understanding:**

Seeing from package flow with Chrome developer tool, when I clicked "vote up" on the question, one POST was sent to server. Stack Overflow server received the POST, increased the vote of this question, then detected that in my session this question is opened in other browser, so server synchronizes this vote up to other pages.

But the question is: why I cannot see package flow from server to browser when synchronization happens?

Could someone briefly explain the workflow and technique behind it?

Comment: I think your browser just checks every once in a while using AJAX.

Comment: @jakekimds That doesn't seem to be the case, since he pointed out that there is no activity in the network tab.

Comment: Do you know if you're also tracking web socket info because according to [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125677/new-feature-real-time-updates-to-questions-answers-and-inbox), (the end of it), vote counts use web sockets.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174764/how-does-stackoverflow-update-the-screen

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174764/how-does-stackoverflow-update-the-screen), it seems that Stack Overflow uses web sockets to synchronize the vote counts and lots of other things, and they only use [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) as a fallback. I hear web sockets are not easily seen in [Firebug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firebug_%28software%29).